# where do I find the angular js fork of spring petclinic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, git, spring-mvc

I read [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs), which states that there is a version of the spring petclinic written in angular js, and available on github.  I clicked the link from the article and was sent to this page on github.  I followed the instructions to:

```
1) In the command line

    git clone https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic.git

2) Inside Eclipse

    File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven project
```

But the result in my local eclipse is the same old petclinic app, with no angular js.  I confirmed this by opening `/spring-petclinic/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/staticFiles.jsp` and saw that it uses jquery.  I then checked at the git link above and looked for branches from the drop down menu, but none of the branches were labeled angular js.

**So where do I download the angular js version of spring petclinic?  And what are the simple (as above) instructions for importing it into eclipse?**

Comment: I think the authors of the article just used the wrong URL.

Comment: @Pointy  So then...  the correct url?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe contact the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which link you clicked. But if you click on "here" in the paragraph

> We have created a fork of the Spring Petclinic application and experimented with converting it to AngularJS (with a new design courtesy of Andrew Abogado). Our fork can be found here.

Then you will be redirected to `https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic` where you can find the AngularJS-based petclinic project.

Comment: I got that link correctly, yes.  But the instructions at that link are what I posted in my OP.  So then perhaps the instructions are wrong.  Can you print the proper git clone url?

Comment: Just use the fork url for cloning (https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic). Obviously they didn't update the readme, when they created the fork. Nevertheless, besides the url the readme still applies.

Comment: Thank you and +1.  That resolved the problem, but I have a downstream problem.  Are you willing to look at it also?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181269/spring-petclinic-angularjs-sample-app-throwing-compilation-errors